# Linux: multiple network connections - 3G/4G / Wifi / LAN / etc; how can i set a preferred network connection to use?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, gateway

I've been looking at how I can setup a laptop that has multiple network interfaces, but a problem exists if all the connections are active, i.e. 3G, WiFi and LAN are all connected, I would like it to default to LAN.

I would like to set "weights" or "priority" to each connection, so that if the LAN is unplugged, it'll default to WiFi - if its in range and working, otherwise, it'll switch and use the 3G dongle;

I've been looking around and I can see that the "metric" counter for route isn't being used for recent kernels. I thought that would be able to set the preferred gateway / connections - but according to the man page:

> man route:
>
> OUTPUT
>
> Metric The  'distance'  to the target
>   (usually counted in hops). It is not
>   used by recent kernels, but may be
>   needed by routing daemons.

So I'm confused, are there any scripts / apps / anything that can detect active network connections, and by way of configuration, send my default gateway network traffic through that interface if its active / alive?

Comment: What tool are you currently using to connect? I use WPA-supplicant, but I'm not sure about its support of 3G connections. This allows you to set up a plain-text config file with the highest priority connections at the top of the list.

Comment: metric is meant to be used for multipath routing IIRC, which worked on 2.2 and 2.4 with a patch by Julian Anastasov IIRC.

Comment: This software of mine might be useful if you don't mind a bit of programming. http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/NCD . It's special kind of programming language especially suited to implementing dynamic network and other configurations. This example shows how to implement priorities, http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/NCD_examples#Multiple_connections_with_priorities . Unfortunately, it doesn't support 3G yet.

Answer (score 2):

Linux usually decides routing based on the interface metric.
Look at 'route -n' and see what it says.  If you have one default gateway (0.0.0.0) with a higher metric, that one will be preferred over all the others.

I'm honestly now sure how linux chooses to route if all the gateways are the same--but the point is that you need to give one default gateway a higher metric.

It's been a while since I've touched Network Manager, but I believe there are settings in there for what metric to give the gateway.

Worst case you could use the 'ip route' command to remove and re-add a gateway with a different metric.  For example:

```
 ip route del 0.0.0.0/0 via 1.2.3.4 dev eth0
 ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 1.2.3.4 dev eth0 metric 1
```