# How do I configure a linux machine to ignore wifi when connected via LAN?

Tags: linux, networking

My laptop is set to automatically connect to my campus wifi network, which is desirable under most circumstances. However, in my office, the signal is quite poor, so I rely on a wired connection. Unfortunately, my machine tries to make both connections. There are two problems:

1. This wifi connection is terrible, and traffic seems to go through that even when I have an ethernet cable.
2. Connecting to wifi in general requires password entry to unlock my keyring.

I think I can take care of problem 1 using [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/291176/linux-multiple-network-connections-3g-4g-wifi-lan-etc-how-can-i-set-a), but problem 2 would best be solved by not trying to make the connection in the first place. Any recommendations for that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to configure the *metric* of the interface, which defines the "delay" or "slowness".

First, install the `ifmetric` program for your distribution, which allows you to easily change the metric for an interface.

Next, you want to edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` to call `ifmetric` when the networking interfaces are connected:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    up ifmetric eth0 10

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    up ifmetric wlan0 20
```

(I'm assuming that `eth0` is the wired interface here, and `wlan0` is the wireless interface. You might have other lines around the `iface` line, the key part that you want to *add* is the

```
    up ifmetric wlan0 20
```

part. This tells the system that it should assume that the `wlan0` interface is twice as slow as the `eth0` interface. This will cause your system to use the wired interface if it is connected, but automatically fall back to the wireless interface.

Depending upon your distribution, there might be a GUI tool to configure this much more easily (such as NetworkManager in the Ubuntu distribution)

Answer (score 1):

If your computer has hardware switch to disable/enable WiFi card you can shut it down while you are in the office.

If your computer does not have a switch, you can shut wireless interface down. By doing:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

Where `wlan0` is name of the wireless interface.

Once you are out of the office you will turn it back on:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

You can obtain list of network interfaces by issuing following command:

```
ifconfig -a
```

That should solve your problem.